# Rails: What's the logic 'behind' the Devise form.submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'm trying to get to grips with Rails and I'm stuck on getting an 8 question multi-choice question quiz working.

I think I understand the MVC side of things. Requests from the browser come through a controller. It asks for info from models, sends it to the views and returns the content to the browser (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I DON'T understand (very clearly, at least) how pages 'know' where to link to. I think, when you generate a resource, you're given a plethora of routes mapped to paths. I don't understand when those paths are relevant.

Could someone please explain to me (step-by-step, if necessary) how the submit button in a Devise form 'knows' where to link to?

My form, so far, looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([current_user]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box :quiz_answers %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I see nothing in there that NAMES a path or a route. How, then, is the link generated?

I have checked rake routes, but I don't think I'm appreciating what is significant about that list. If someone could explain the MEANING behind it, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it.

There are several types of methods that you can send through web page:
-GET
-POST
-DELETE
-PUT

Get sends parameters through link. you can see its parameters in URL, for instance www.google.ba?you_are=user, you_are is parameter and its value is user.

Post sends parameters through package so you can't see anything in the url, yet informations are there.

Other methods are variations for POST method for restful service.

For your question, devise creates by default some routes that are not clearly visible in routes.rb. Any request that comes across your webpage goes to the routes.rb, checks where should it be delegated then send that to corresponding controller. Controller then takes parameters do some logic(delegates it to services and other things), prepares models for show and then delegates it to template. Then, template with all informations(rendered) is sent to web browser.

There is one thing to mention, resource or devise creates default actions for every method for corresponding action. In this case you just need to set model and it knows where to delegates it.

Here are my routes for devise ( some of them are custom):

```
new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                    user_sessions#new
                   user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                    user_sessions#create
           destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                   user_sessions#destroy
                  user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                                   passwords#create
              new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                               passwords#new
             edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                              passwords#edit
                                PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                   passwords#update
                                PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                   passwords#update
       cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                                     users#cancel
              user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                                            users#create
          new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                                    users#new
         edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                                       users#edit
                                PATCH    /users(.:format)                                            users#update
                                PUT      /users(.:format)                                            users#update
                                DELETE   /users(.:format)                                            users#destroy
              user_confirmation POST     /users/confirmation(.:format)                               confirms#create
          new_user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                           confirms#new
                                GET      /users/confirmation(.:format)                               confirms#show
```

Use rake routes command in terminal to find out all your routes.

Comment: I've already got non-devise pages linking, so I don't think I need to do more of that. Devise might know where to 'delegate' a request, but I don't know where it's sending a request. I'd like to know where (and, hopefully, why) it's linking to. I have repeatedly checked rake routes, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to deduce from the list.

Comment: Look at the third column. It says (e.g. users#edit). That means it will redirect to users controller, edit action. So first parameter is users(UsersController)  and another is action inside that controller (in the example edit). Every MVC application has to know where to send its request and thats why we need routes, and thats why requests goes/links to.